# can't access docsis modem webpage

Tags: networking, openwrt

I have docsis modem working on IP address 192.168.0.1 whereas my wifi router is configured on 192.168.0.2. I can access wifi router's webpage but not the modem's webpage. I am not even able to ping my docsis modem. Everything works fine if I configure my wifi router to 192.168.1.1 but I would not like to do so since my other devices are configured for 192.168.0.* addresses.

Should I add some route in wifi router's settings? Help please! I am using openWrt.

Answer (score 0):

The router is the splitting point between networks.  What you are trying to do is put the same network on both sides of the router.  (192.168.0.x) network.  The router thinks that 192.168.0.1 is on 'your' network side and so it tries to find it there.  That's why when you do change your network to 192.168.1.x, the router then knows 192.168.0.x is not your network and looks out the 'internet/wan' port.